# Does Firestore allow using exists() in security rules for collection groups?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Does Firestore allow using `exists()` in security rules for collection groups?

Using the rules playground, I get this error:

> Error running simulation — Error: simulator.rules line [36], column [22]. Function not found error: Name: [exists].; Error: Invalid argument provided to call. Function: [exists], Argument: ["||invalid_argument||"]

For these rules:

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    
    // permissions (collection group) - works
    match /{path=**}/member/{permission} {
      // let users read their own permissions
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.userId
    }

    // options (collection group) doesn't work
    // Collection groups can't have paths so this is only way afaik
    match /{path=**}/option/{option} {
      allow read: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/project/$(resource.data.projectId)/member/$(request.auth.uid));
    }

  }
}
```

Note: line numbers in error message are off bc of redaction. But it seems like it's saying the exists function is not available.

Comment: `exist` should exist in every scope where documents may exist, but you have a closing` }` on line 4 that probably throws the parser off.

Comment: appreciate the response but the extra `}` was a type during redaction. Code example corrected but still have the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Posting as community wiki based on @FrankvanPuffelen's answer:

> `exists()` should exist in every scope where documents may exist, but you have a closing `}` on line 4 that probably throws the parser off.

You can check these documentations on writing Cloud Firestore Security Rules:

- [Get started with Cloud Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started)
- [Access other documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents)